# Ctrl-c out of Guard returns interrupt notices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, rspec, rspec-rails, guard

I run guard, it's working fine, but when I Ctrl-C out, it gives me the standard By bye... and then the output I've pasted below. Could anyone explain what's going on? Doesn't seem to be operating incorrectly, I would just like to know.

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:tasks user$ guard
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00007 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
Bye bye...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/listen-0.4.7/lib/listen/turnstile.rb:19:in `pop': Interrupt
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/listen-0.4.7/lib/listen/turnstile.rb:19:in `wait'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.2.3/lib/guard.rb:163:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.2.3/lib/guard/cli.rb:100:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.15.4/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.2.3/bin/guard:6
    from /usr/bin/guard:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/guard:23
Users-MacBook-Pro:tasks user$
```

Comment: Ctrl-C is keyboard interrupt. It sends SIGINT to process (usually program will terminate)

Comment: Yeah, I understand what ctrl-c does, I'm just curious about the output. Tutorials that I have found do not show any output upon exiting Guard except for Bye bye...

Comment: It looks like backtrace where the program stopped.